Crack in the corner of the wall
I just realized that in the corner of two walls I have a crack, it is deep, both walls are separated, I do not know how long they have been there, this crack is on the second floor, and the crack does not reach the floor below, what should I do, should I worry?
About 15-17 years ago approximately the house next to ours collapsed to build a garage. Also, the crack is quite deep, it looks as if the wall and the pillar are separated.
The house is quite old, I think it dates back to 1940 or even earlier. In the 90's part of the house was renovated. The crack between the two walls, from the ceiling to the floor.

Did the house next door collapse or was taken down?  One crack should be watched.  Pictures taken with a tape measure every few months.  Two cracks on different corners of the same wall is a worry.
